# Is there a syntax to prevent mutation of original array when the original array is passed are function parameters?

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a class method that is below, is there some syntax that will give compiler warning or error to prevent mutating the "remove" itself?

```
public class Organizer {

   public List<Item> items;

   public Package CreatePackage(IEnumerable<Item> remove) {

       // Is there some syntax that will give compiler warning or error to prevent mutating the "remove" itself?
       this.items.RemoveWhere(i => remove.Contains(i));

       // unexpected "remove" becomes empty.
       return new Package(remove);
   }
}
```

Somewhere in other parts of the code

```
var package = organizer.CreatePackage(organizer.items);
```

EDIT: Currently, I temporarily solve this by putting remove into another array. `var _remove = remove.ToArray()`.

Comment: Use `IReadOnlyCollection` or `ImmutableArray`?

Comment: This is not something that can be solved by static analysis. Whether or not `remove == items` can only be determined at runtime.

Comment: I don't fully understand the "in" keyword for parameters, will that help in this case? Basically I am looking for a method signature that is as fool proof as possible, and I am hoping there's a language feature I can learn to apply here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a way for the compiler to reliably know whether someone passed a reference to the same list as an argument to your method. You could theoretically write an analyzer that checks specifically for the `organizer.CreatePackage(organizer.items)` pattern, but that wouldn't catch less obvious cases.

You could do a runtime check to make sure `remove != items`, but that doesn't address the larger problem: how do you know whether the person calling your method intended you to mutate the list they originally assigned to `organizer.items`? You'll want to think about ways to avoid mutating collections that didn't belong to this class in the first place.

One way would be not to mutate the list at all, and just change the local `items` reference you're using.

```
    public Package CreatePackage(IEnumerable<Item> remove)
    {
        this.items = this.items.Except(remove).ToList();
        return new Package(remove);
    }

void Main()
{
    var items = new Item[] { new(), new() };
    var organizer = new Organizer { items = items.ToList() };
    organizer.CreatePackage(items);
    items.Should().NotBeEmpty();
    organizer.items.Should().BeEmpty();
}
```

But you could go a step further and isolate the local list by creating a copy when you construct your class. That way you're free to mutate `items` itself without worrying about messing up other people's lists.

```
public class Organizer
{
    public IEnumerable<Item> Items => items.AsReadOnly();
    private List<Item> items;

    public Organizer(IEnumerable<Item> items)
    {
        this.items = items.ToList();
    }

    public Package CreatePackage(IEnumerable<Item> remove)
    {
        this.items.RemoveAll(i => remove.Contains(i));
        return new Package(remove);
    }
}

void Main()
{
    var items = new Item[]{new(), new()};
    var organizer = new Organizer(items);
    organizer.CreatePackage(items);

    items.Should().NotBeEmpty();
    organizer.Items.Should().BeEmpty();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can avoid all the troubles (and also avoid multiple enumerations of IEnumerable (which can be not trivial / expensive, e.g. with filtering and sorting)) by making a copy of the sequence:

```
public Package CreatePackage(IEnumerable<Item> remove)
{
   var copy = remove.ToList();

   this.items.RemoveWhere(i => copy.Contains(i));

   return new Package(copy);
}
```